# Using websocket for notifying frontend

Tags: javascript, go, websocket

There is backend using golang,frontend - JS. The task is to get updates on frontend (JS) from backend.

back code (Go):

```golang
func ini_WS(wsChan chan string) websocket.Upgrader { // invoke from main
    var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
        ReadBufferSize:  1024,
        WriteBufferSize: 1024,
        CheckOrigin: func(r *http.Request) bool {
            return true
        },
    }

    var flag int64
    go http.ListenAndServe(":8080", http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ws, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        if atomic.CompareAndSwapInt64(&flag, 0, 1) {
            go func() {
                for data := range wsChan {
                    ws.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte(data))
                    fmt.Println("data sent")
                }
            }()
        }
    }))

    return upgrader
}
```

During  work of the app put data to the channel wsChan. And it works till refresh the web page. As soon as I refresh the page frontend doe not get messages (although according the debugger backend send them). It may be supposed to be done in another way. Please tell me how to realize this  task in he correct way

front (JS)

```js
conn = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");
conn.onmessage = function (event) {
   // ........
};
```

Comment: Check the error returned by [`ws.WriteMessage`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Conn.WriteMessage) (the connection will be dropped when you refresh the page).

Answer (score 0):

solution:
you need to close the previous one before creating a new connection

```golang
var wsconn *websocket.Conn
var flag int64
go http.ListenAndServe(":8080", http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        var err error
        if wsconn != nil {
            wsconn.Close()
        }
        wsconn, err = upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
// .....
```

Comment: Note that this will fail if a second user attempts to connect - the first user will be disconnected (that might be OK for your use-case but most web apps need to support multiple connections).

Comment: There is a data race on wsconn.